# Time on page calculated only for specific segment in Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

### Goal

I would like to see what is the time on page for user who is logged in. Eliminate from reports time, while user was not logged in.

To have ability to distinguish between time on page while user **is not logged in** and time on page while he **is logged in**.

### Setup

Let's say we have:

- Traffic variable **User logged in** as a *prop1* where is *true* or *false*.
- Traffic variable **Time from previous event** as a *prop2* in **seconds**
- eVar1 **duplicating** prop1 | expire after event5
- eVar2 **duplicating** prop2 | expire after event5
- event4 - **User logged in**
- event5 - **User logged out**

### Time between events

From an article about measuring time between events (https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-analytics-questions/calculate-time-between-success-events/qaq-p/302787)

```
if (s.events && (s.events + ",").indexOf("event4,") > -1) {
  s.prop2 = "start"
}

if (s.events && (s.events + ",").indexOf("event5,") > -1) {
  s.prop2 = "stop"
}

s.prop2 = s.getTimeToComplete(s.prop2, "TTC", 0);


s.getTimeToComplete = new Function("v", "cn", "e", "var s=this,d=new Date,x=d,k;if(!s.ttcr){e=e?e:0;if(v=='start'||v=='stop')s.ttcr=1;x.setTime(x.getTime()+e* 86400000);if(v=='start'){s.c_w(cn,d.getTime(),e?x:0);return '';}if(v=='stop'){k=s.c_r(cn);if(!s.c_w(cn,'',d)||!k)return '';v=(d.getTime()-k)/1000;var td=86400,th=3600,tm=60,r=5,u,un;if(v>td){u=td;un='days';}else if(v>th){u=th;un='hours';}else if(v>tm){r=2;u=tm;un='minutes';}else{r=.2;u=1;un='seconds';}v=v*r/u;return (Math.round(v)/r)+' '+un;}}return '';");
```

### Time spent overview

From adobe docs (https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/analytics/components/metrics/time-spent.html)

> A “sequence” is a consecutive set of hits where a given variable
> contains the same value (whether by being set, spread forward, or
> persisted). For example, prop1 “A” has two sequences: hits 1 & 2 and
> hit 6. Values on the last hit of the visit do not start a new sequence
> because the last hit has no time spent. Average time spent on site
> uses sequences in the denominator.

So I guess I will uses prop1 as a denominator for logged in user state to count time between event in prop2 properly.

### Problem

I am not pretty sure, If this approach is enough to correctly measure time spent only while user is logged in. I would appreciate some hints, how to set up eVars correctly or if I understand sequence denominator correctly.

I also set up eVars with terminating event5, but I am not sure, If this leads to desired behavior.

If you also solve this problem before, please can you lead me, how you define your segment or condition in reports.

Answer (score 1):

GetTimeBetweenEvents plugin should do a job. However, it seems like it was rewritten, I have found in documentation example calls also using Launch plugins extension:
https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/analytics/implementation/vars/plugins/gettimebetweenevents.html

**From Adobe documentation**

> Install the plug-in using AppMeasurement Copy and paste the following
> code anywhere in the AppMeasurement file after the Analytics tracking
> object is instantiated (using s_gi ). Preserving comments and version
> numbers of the code in your implementation helps Adobe with
> troubleshooting any potential issues.

```
/******************************************* BEGIN CODE TO DEPLOY *******************************************/
/* Adobe Consulting Plugin: getTimeBetweenEvents v2.1 (Requires formatTime and inList plug-ins) */
s.getTimeBetweenEvents=function(ste,rt,stp,res,cn,etd,fmt,bml,rte){var s=this;if("string"===typeof ste&&"undefined"!==typeof rt&&"string"===typeof stp&&"undefined"!==typeof res){cn=cn?cn:"s_tbe";etd=isNaN(etd)?1:Number(etd);var f=!1,g=!1,n=!1, p=ste.split(","),q=stp.split(",");rte=rte?rte.split(","):[];for(var h=s.c_r(cn),k,v=new Date,r=v.getTime(),c=new Date,a=0; a<rte.length;++a)s.inList(s.events,rte[a])&&(n=!0);c.setTime(c.getTime()+864E5*etd);for(a=0;a<p.length&&!f&&(f=s.inList(s.events,p[a]),!0!==f);++a);for(a=0;a<q.length&&!g&&(g=s.inList(s.events,q[a]),!0!==g);++a);1===p.length&&1===q.length&&ste===stp&&f&&g?(h&&(k=(r-h)/1E3),s.c_w(cn,r,etd?c:0)):(!f||1!=rt&&h||s.c_w(cn,r,etd?c:0),g&&h&&(k=(v.getTime()-h)/1E3,!0===res&&(n=!0)));!0===n&&(c.setDate( c.getDate()-1),s.c_w(cn,"",c));return k?s.formatTime(k,fmt,bml):""}};

/* Adobe Consulting Plugin: formatTime v1.1 (Requires inList plug-in) */
s.formatTime=function(ns,tf,bml){var s=this;if(!("undefined"===typeof ns||isNaN(ns)||0>Number(ns))){if("string"===typeof tf&&"d"===tf||("string"!==typeof tf||!s.inList("h,m,s",tf))&&86400<=ns){tf=86400;var d="days";bml=isNaN(bml)?1:tf/(bml*tf)} else"string"===typeof tf&&"h"===tf||("string"!==typeof tf||!s.inList("m,s",tf))&&3600<=ns?(tf=3600,d="hours", bml=isNaN(bml)?4: tf/(bml*tf)):"string"===typeof tf&&"m"===tf||("string"!==typeof tf||!s.inList("s",tf))&&60<=ns?(tf=60,d="minutes",bml=isNaN(bml)?2: tf/(bml*tf)):(tf=1,d="seconds",bml=isNaN(bml)?.2:tf/bml);ns=Math.round(ns*bml/tf)/bml+" "+d;0===ns.indexOf("1 ")&&(ns=ns.substring(0,ns.length-1));return ns}};

/* Adobe Consulting Plugin: inList v2.1 */
s.inList=function(lv,vtc,d,cc){if("string"!==typeof vtc)return!1;if("string"===typeof lv)lv=lv.split(d||",");else if("object"!== typeof lv)return!1;d=0;for(var e=lv.length;d<e;d++)if(1==cc&&vtc===lv[d]||vtc.toLowerCase()===lv[d].toLowerCase())return!0;return!1};
/******************************************** END CODE TO DEPLOY ********************************************/
```

**Then your eVar may looks like:**

```
s.eVar1 = s.getTimeBetweenEvents("event1", true, "event2", true, "", 0, "s", 2, "event3");
```

Comment: thank you matej, this seems to be exactly what I am looking for